# Is it feasible to use SSI (Combine CSS/JS files using htaccess) to speedup website?

Tags: css, .htaccess, concrete5, ssi

I went through this article today 
http://isitvivid.com/blog/combining-your-cssjs-files-with-htaccess

and found that we can use htaccess file to combile CSS and JS files and this thing is called Server Side Includes.

I am already usign gZip compression, Keep Alive feature and Cache for my website. By using SSI to combine CSS/JS will help to speed up website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you could speed up your site a little bit by combining assets, but unless you're loading hundreds of things synchronously you shouldn't expect more than a micro optimization. You're more likely to get speed benefits by using the `defer` script tag attributes when loading your script tags and minimizing your css files.

Comment: Or simply use HTTP 2 ;)